# Select partial column title in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering if there is a way to select part of a column in mysql. For example, I want to select all statistics from my table that end in "_sep_2012". This would give me access to 1_sep_2012, 2_sep_2012, 3_sep_2012 etc...Is there a way to do this?

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT %_sep_2012% FROM statistics WHERE id = '$id'");

$array = mysql_fetch_row($query);

$monthly_total = $array[0];

echo "$monthly_total";
?>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have more than one column representing a date?

Comment: That sounds like a very bad DB design.

Comment: Maybe ill rethink how I'm doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question it should be possible to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE datecolumn LIKE '%_sep_2012'
```

Not saying it's nice but it should get the data you need. You can add GROUP BY clauses to do a  count or sum to get your total like:

```
SELECT datecolumn, SUM(amountcolumn) FROM statistics WHERE datecolumn LIKE '%_sep_2012' GROUP BY datecolumn
```

Comment: There is no `datecolumn`. Th columns themselves are named as: `1_sep_2012`

Comment: Ahh it got more ugly then I expected. Then only option would be to generate a string with all fields. But instead you could also just get the total record and then do your calculation in PHP. It won't be a nice solution anyway which is structurally correct. The good solution would likely be adding a table with a column for the date and one for the value.

Comment: how many records could that hold? The reason that I am doing it is because I need to be able to add up the total number of hits the various id's get on a daily to monthly basis, etc... I know that if I store every single hit, my DB will get quite large, so I have a table of INT values that represent every day of the year..

Comment: You are doing a structure like data warehousing. In general: First make the "correct" structure. So a well normalized structure. If that performs (or you foresee) bad then you can add another table counting the totals as a sort of cache. There are good solutions for that but preferably first make it working with the correct structure. Then optimize when you need it. If it is too slow really and you do lots of reads a cache is always possible to add. Could be both a table of totals as well other caching solutions depending on your environment available.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in PHP:

```
for($i=1;$i<32;$i++)
  printf("`%d_sep_2012`, ", $i);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this. Is this a bad way to structure this table? The reason that I am doing it is because I need to be able to add up the total number of hits the various id's get on a daily to monthly basis, etc... I know that if I store every single hit, my DB will get quite large, so I have a table of INT values that represent every day of the year...

Comment: @Brandon Even if you store everyday entry in a new row, for 10 years, it'll still get no more than 3700 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE datecolumn LIKE '%_sep_2012' and id = '$id'
```